# How to limit Google Scholar to peer-reviewed papers?

Tags: google-scholar

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) is great to get a quick overview of scientific publications. However, it also gives you textbooks, theses and so forth. I would like to limit its results to include only peer-reviewed (conference) papers. Do you know of a way to do so?

Comment: big problem with google scholar is that the results only have to look scientific, but they don't actually have to have any scientific value in them. if you are aware of that it's still a great source for scientific papers.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch: Yes, but if you limit the results to peer-reviews and the conference where it was published has a good reputation, you have cut out most of the stuff you don't want.

Comment: Conference papers are not peer-reviewed; you want journal articles instead

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct means to only show peer-reviewed work; as Google Scholar also posts legal summaries, and other major journal articles from the Online WorldCat.  However, there are means by which you can help narrow down your results, to show what you are looking for (within reason).

See this PDF:

[Using Google Scholar to Find Peer-Reviewed Articles](https://library.lanecc.edu/sites/default/files/handouts/googlescholar2sides.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

For peer-reviewed articles, you should use the subscription databases of you college library or public library. Most of these databases can filter peer-reviewed articles from your search results.